# Как сделать чтобы элементы при прокрутке меняли margin-left или подобное, если есть "преграда"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такой код

```css
.box-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.items {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="box-bg"></div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы когда элементы прокручиваются, и если на пути прокрутки элемент подходит до блока .box-bg, то элемент сдвигался бы влево?...

Вот примерно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял...

```js
var box_bg = document.querySelector('.box-bg'),
  item = document.getElementsByClassName('item'),
  items = document.querySelector('.items');

window.onload = function() {
  mgLeft()
}

function mgLeft() {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    if ((item[i].getBoundingClientRect().top > 150) || (item[i].getBoundingClientRect().top < 40)) {
      item[i].style.marginLeft = '0';
    } else {
      item[i].style.marginLeft = '-55px';
    }
  }
}
items.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  mgLeft()
})
```

```css
.box-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  background: #2cc;
}

.items {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transition: all .1s;
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="box-bg"></div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
  <div class="item">item7</div>
  <div class="item">item8</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кажется не совсем то, что нужно. Автор видимо хочет, чтобы не `box-bg` сдвигался, а чтобы элемент с классом `item` сдвигался